# Selecting sibling text with XPath

Tags: xpath

[image]

I need to select the sibling text after the first @class. First I used:

```
//td[@class='schoolsContactsHeader']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

but I'm getting a few white spaces. Then I tried:

```
normalize-space(//td[@class='schoolsContactsHeader']/following-sibling::text()[1])
```

and I'm getting, **String:** and nothing else. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering myself. The result was `(//td[@class = 'schoolsContactsHeader'])[1]`
[image]